# Nginx Kubernetes Ingress does not serve .ttf or .woff files

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, annotations, mime-types, nginx-ingress

My Nginx Kubernetes ingress I think is not properly configured to serve .ttf file.

On safari work properly, but on chrome I have an error about cors allow. 
I checked my .conf Nginx file on my deployed ingress and "more_set_headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is configured.

I think I need to add some annotations on mime.types or gzip config.

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: cc-i
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: myapp.com
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: cc-s
              servicePort: 80
      - http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: cc-s
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Could you share your some of your nginx.conf ? Did you set values like here: https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-setup-server-to-serve-fonts#nginx ? Only chrome or FF is also affected? You are using On-Prem or local?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557718/8881622

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted. It will be more visible for other people with similar issue.

Comment: i need to wait tomorrow.. i cant now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CDN services has a cors configuration that need to be configured.
In my case i added a cors authorized domain on my digitalocean space.
This solved on firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Verify wich type of installation you have made and verify you have the `nginx-config` configmap. See [docs](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/configmap-and-annotations.md#using-configmap)

If you don't have, create one and set this in the `data` area:

```
data:
  gzip_types: application/x-font-ttf application/font-woff
```

And if you need more `gzip_type` you could add too. [Here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#gzip-types) are the default values.

If the problem is the gzip config like you say this will solve your problem.

Comment: there was a top level cors block on cdn service space. however thank you!